# Word to describe 2 perspectives

Tags: single-word-requests

I have 2 people talking on the phone to each other.

Person A is calling person B.
Person B is receiving a call from person A.

If you recorded both directions, they would be identical except for whom was calling whom.

Is there a word that would describe these 2 identical calls?

I've come up with :

- Duplicate (but this infers a copy instead of 2 separate experiences)
- Concurrent ( but this infers another call that happened at the same time instead of the same call)

Comment: Bidirectional? Provide the sentence you'd use the word in.

Comment: Can you give a short example? Are you referring to the same words heard from 2 different points of view, or two complementary things that will together form a conversation?

Comment: Talking of words, it is "two".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a comment that has been deleted which had the answer I decided to use.

Symmetric.

Person As recording is symmetric to person Bs recording.
This perfect describes the relationship between the two.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are two calls at all. You have recorded a conversation.
If two people were talking to each other across a table, you wouldn't call that two speeches, it would be one conversation.

(I suggest *... except for **who** was calling whom.*.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a call that goes something like...

> Person A: Hello!
>
> Person B: Hello!
>
> A: How are you doing?
>
> B: How are *you* doing?
>
> A: Oh, okay.
>
> B: Oh! Okay.
>
> A: Bye!
>
> B: Bye!

I would probably resort to extending usages from visual context. I might reasonably call the two sides of the conversation "mirror images" of each other. I might describe the conversation as "perfectly symmetrical," as the show *Futurama* describes a fight in which two combatants use identical attacks simultaneously.